# How do I cache MySQL geospatial query?

Tags: mysql, search, indexing, redis, geospatial

I have an API server with redis cache and MySQL database. I'll save geospatial data in MySQL, and I want to provide an API for **finding some points in a given polygon**.

For example,
`GET /api/v1/stores?boundary=45.9527556390094, -113.39711818925397,26.27578565710524, -79.64711879402736` (left top, right bottom & latitude, longitude)

I want to put **redis cache between API and MySQL** because I think DB will make bottleneck while processing API requests. I will do geospatial queries using `ST_GEOMFROMTEXT, ST_WITHIN` in MySQL.

I found it very difficult to design cache key for geospatial query results from MySQL. Every user will give very different geospatial boundary values, so cannot make the given boundary values as redis keys.

In this case, how do I cache the geospatial queries from MySQL?

Comment: Different boundary boxes will (usually) return different resultsets, so it's not really clear which cached result you want for a different boundary box. If you can specify that, it may naturally emerge the key.

Comment: You might be able to do something clever with GeoSets in Redis. Maybe even just store the geo data there instead of using MySQL for it.

Comment: @GuyRoyse Thank you, but is it okay to store whole geospatial data in Redis? I think redis is best suitable for caching frequently viewed partial data among all data.
Honestly speaking, I don't have too much geospatial data for now, but I want to consider scalability in the future.

Comment: Depends on how much data you anticipate having.

Comment: Do you have a `SPATIAL` index on that table?

Comment: @RickJames Yes, I already applied `SPATIAL` index on the geospatial data table. I want to know if there is more efficient way by using redis between API and MySQL.

Comment: Have you timed it without Redis?  Maybe Spatial is "fast enough".

Comment: @RickJames I'm more concerned about throughput than latency.

Comment: How many rows in the table you are searching?  What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  How much RAM do you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will you get *exactly* the same polygon each time?  I suspect not.  The lat/lng are computed from the GPS coordinates of a cellphone?  If not *exactly* the same, there is nothing cachable *after* the query.  The only hope is to cache the running of the query.

Improving latency helps with throughput.  Unless the entire dataset won't fit in the buffer_pool, I would expect you to be able to run perhaps 1000 queries per second like that (without Redis).

More discussion of "find nearest":  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/find_nearest_in_mysql
It includes a table of how many decimal places are useful.  (6 or 7 decimal places should be quite sufficient.)

Comment: Thank you so much for taking an interest in my question and trying to solve it together.
I'll wait a little longer for the other answers and accept your answer if there aren't better ones. :)